# define a style for dropdownmenu navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I do have a bootstrap navbar with a specific color for the navbar and its letters as show in the css below

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color:#2d4c60 !important; 
}
       nav.navbar {
    background-color: #2d4c60;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
    color: white;
}
```

[image]

and everythings works fine excepts for the dropdownmenu "Ayuda", it shows the options but all in white so the user cannot be sure of the option selected

[image]

and what i want is the dropdown to have the same style of the navbar

besides of that I would like the navbar-brand to has the same look (color white) as the rest of the options, could you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .dropdown-menu class has a default background-color of #fff, that's why you can't see the words. If you want it to be the same color as the nav, then set .dropdown-menu{ background-color: 2d4c60;}

Comment: thanks, now the dropdown has the same navbar color with the letters in color white but when i pass the mouse' cursor over the option all th eoption turns white so the user can read the menu option, could you p´lease help me

Comment: You will probably need to change this .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,  to be a different background-color . The default background color for the hover is almost white.